# Is there a difference between add_field in grok and mutate filters of logstash?

Tags: logstash-grok

I'm trying to add fields while parsing the logs in logstash for the below log record.

> 64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:05:49 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables HTTP/1.1" 401 12846

I want to know if there is a difference when add_field is used under grok filter and when it is used under mutate filter plugins.

Answer (score 0):

The function of the add_field is same in both the filters.